# Optional dependencies in drake?

Tags: r, drake-r-package

Consider the situation where I have some dependencies that are "optional" - sometimes I want to include them in my processing chain, sometimes I don't. e.g.

```
the.plan <-
 drake_plan(A,
            B,
            C,
            combined_target=target(list(A,B,C)),
            further_processing=target(my_fn(combined_target)))
```

Depending on how I configure my processing chain, sometimes we want to include all of A, B and C, other times one or more of them are not required  and therefore should not be included. How can I best structure such a plan to achieve this?

Best wishes,

Mark

Comment: Naively, I would recommend just modifying the command of `combined_target` as needed, e.g. `list(A, B)` if `C` should be dropped. Or, keep the original `list(A, B, C)` and just write `my_fn()` to exclude what is not needed from `combined_target`. Anything wrong with these options?

Comment: Thanks. Is this something that might be handled easier in the `targets`packge instead? I've started looking at it, but haven't tried it out in earnest as yet....

Comment: I think in this situation, both `drake` and `targets` should be equally accommodating.